# ArcGIS Raster Calculator VS QGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

Are there any major differences between ArcGIS Raster Calculator and QGIS Raster Calculator?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you need to calculate? Many users know only one of the two solutions well enough to write an answer but could provide an answer for one of the two.

Comment: I was just curious. I mostly use ArcGIS Raster Calculator however we only have limited SA licences so occasionally I have to use the QGIS Raster Calculator, and I wanted to know any differences anyone's noticed.